# How to process more that one XML document in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

Is there any trick to match two XML by one XSLT? I mean the way I can apply XSLT to a parameter passed.

For example (I missed declarations to be short). XML1: XML to be transformed:

```
<myData>
   <Collection>

   </Collection>
</myData>
```

XSLT need to be applied to the previous XML:

```
<xsl:param name='items' />
<xsl:template match='Collection'>
    <!-- some transformation here -->
</xsl:template>
```

XML2: XML data passed as the parameter 'items':

```
<newData>
   <Item>1</Item>
   <Item>2</Item>
   <Item>3</Item>
</newData>
```

And I need to create a set of nodes in the 'Collection' node in XML1 for each 'Item' element in XML2 using XSLT. And I do not know what XML2 contains exactly at design time. It is generated at runtime, so I can't place it inside XSLT, I know only its schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1). You could generate the XSLT instead of using a static XSLT:

transform xml2 with xslt1 which leads to xslt2
transform xml1 with xslt2 which leads to the desired output

(2). You could use the `document()` function to load xml2. This requires xml2 to be persisted to disk or to be accessible by a uri.

```
      <xsl:copy-of select="document('xml2.xml')//newData" />
```

Answer (score 1):

**Read about and use the standard XSLT function [`document()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#function-document).**